# how to pass data in perform segue sender through protocol & delegate from a UICollectionViewCell inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview, delegates, segue, swift5, swift-protocols

1. I have VC(a) with TableView
2. Inside the UITableViewCell.xib I installed a UICollectionView
3. UICollectionViewCell registered inside the UITableViewCell.xib of
   course.
4. I want to perform segue from VC(a) to VC(b) when UICollectionViewCell didSelected
5. And since the UICollectionViewCell is registered inside the
   UITableViewCell.xib so I can't use  performSegue(withIdentifier:
   String, sender: Any) inside the .xib file because it is not
   inherited from UIViewController

I did some searches in StackOverFlow and I found methods to perform segue by creating a custom delegator protocol I applied the protocol and everything seems OK except the sender!!

I know how to use it inside VC without protocol but I don't know how to use it after applying the protocol

I'm new to Swift Language and so please help me to complete my code

Here below is the UITableViewCell.xib code

```
protocol MyCustomCellDelegator {
    func cellWasPressed()
}


class AdminPList_TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var delegate: MyCustomCellDelegator?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        setupCell()
        getFProducts()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    func getFProducts() {
        productAPI.GetAllproducts { (appendThisProduct) in
            self.FP_Array.append(appendThisProduct)
            self.CollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    var FP_Array : [productObject] = []    
}

extension AdminPList_TableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func setupCell() {
        CollectionView.delegate = self ; CollectionView.dataSource = self

        CollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "FproductsCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FPcell")

//      CollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "TproductsCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TPcell")
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize(width: self.CollectionView.frame.size.width-10, height: self.CollectionView.frame.size.height)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {  // make spacing between each cell
        return 10
    }

    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return FP_Array.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let FPcell = CollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FPcell", for: indexPath) as! FproductsCell
        
        FPcell.UpdateFP_cell_Content(RetrivedProducts: FP_Array[indexPath.row])
        
        return FPcell
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let selectedProduct = FP_Array[indexPath.row] // I want to pass it to sender in perform segue un ProductsLibrary Class

//      print (selectedProduct.productName)
        self.delegate?.cellWasPressed()
        
    }
}
```

Help me to pass selectedProduct to perform segue in below protocol

And here below is the VC(a) where the UITableView is installed:

```
class ProductsLibrary : UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupCell()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

    
}



extension ProductsLibrary : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MyCustomCellDelegator {
    
    func cellWasPressed(withData:  productObject) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditProduct", sender: self)
        
    }
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let next = segue.destination as? ProductManagement{
            print ("Editing Product is Active")

              let product = sender as? productObject
                print(product) //it shows nil !!!
                next.EditingProduct = product
        }
    }
    
    func setupCell() {
        TableView.delegate = self ; TableView.dataSource = self
        
        TableView.register(UINib(nibName: "AdminPList_TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PLcell")
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                    
        return 3
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PLcell", for: indexPath) as! AdminPList_TableViewCell
            
        cell.delegate = self
        
        
            return cell
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        return self.TableView.frame.size.height/3
    }
    

    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I started learning the **delegation** pattern I always made some mistakes. So I make a rule for myself. When you have to implement a delegate always remind **6 steps**.

**The First 3 steps are for the class that will pass the data or write protocol**, here your **AdminPList_TableViewCell** is that class. The 3 steps are

1. Write a protocol (a bunch of method declaration) // you did it.
2. Declare a protocol variable inside the class that will pass the data. // you did that too (*var delegate: MyCustomCellDelegator?*)
3. Call the methods you declared. // you did that (*self.delegate?.cellWasPressed()*)

**The Last 3 steps are for the class that will conform that protocol**, here **ProductsLibrary** is that class.

4. Conform that protocol in that class which will implement those methods. // here you did that (*extension ProductsLibrary: ..., MyCustomCellDelegator*)
5. Assign delegate to self, but what is self here? well, *self* is the ProductsLibrary which has been delegated! // you missed that
6. Implement the protocol methods. // you did that :)

How to solve this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                    
    ...
    cell.delegate = self // you missed this line
    ...
    return cell
}
```

Now for passing **selectedProduct** just change the protocol method definition everywhere.

```
protocol MyCustomCellDelegator {
    func cellWasPressed(withData: productObject)
}
```

Then call from the `didSelectItemAt` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedProduct = FP_Array[indexPath.row] // I want to pass it to sender in perform segue un ProductsLibrary Class
    self.delegate?.cellWasPressed(withData: selectedProduct)
        
}
```

Now use it inside the method body.

```
func cellWasPressed(withData data: productObject) {
    //now use the data and write your necessary code.
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditProduct", sender: self)

}
```

Hope it will help you :).

Comment: Dear @Asif Mujtaba Firstly thank you for editing & improving my question... and thank you for the good explanation and your useful steps in implementing delegation protocols....all what you explained is clear and understood for me.. but I am still unable  to pass (let selectedProduct) in sender in the VC(a) even after I assigned delegate to self as you instructed me!

Comment: Now I'm sure that the protocol is 100% is corrected and there is no mistakes... let's jump to the main issue in my question... how to pass ( let selctedProduct) to the other VC... please remember I' new and beginner to Swift so please keep patient with me and thank you in advance!

Comment: One more thing... how can I use func cellWasPressed() and implement some codes inside it?

Comment: Ok, for passing data is also simple, I've updated my answer, please take a look. Since it helped you, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you again for updating your good answer, but my friend you forgot to tell me what shall I put in sender of ( override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) ).

Comment: The problem is I can't import the value of let selectedProduct inside (didSelectItemAt indexPath) of collectioViewCell and it is completely not imported ... So I can't export it in sender to the new VC when I implement: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

Comment: Keep a variable in  **ProductsLibrary** class of *productObject* type. set the value of the variable inside delegate method, like , var productData: productObject? and productData = data. Now create another variable of type *productObject* in your target ViewController. Then in prepare(for segue:..) method get the target viewController and set the property by *productData* variable. Like , targetViewController.data = productData. For getting viewController in prepareForSegue method, follow @fabriciomasiero answer below.

Comment: @Zulrarnayn Bro Jazak Allah Hayran, you solved my problem, finally it works and you've filled up what my code was missing I really appreciate your help and patient... I marked your professional answer as accepted... you too kindly don't forget to vote up my question if you see it useful for beginner like me. ( please vote it up )

Comment: @let.Simoo barakallah. Keep coding :)

Comment: Dear @Zulrarnayn please I want to add one more question about confirming protocol... I created a subClass and I want to import (UITextfield.text) to inside it... I did follow your 6 steps but when I reached to step(4) I couldn't confirm the protocol because the subClass is not UIViewController property! and I got this error: (Closure expression is unused).. how to confirm the new protocol please??

Answer (score 1):

how are you?

Maybe your **delegate** is nil, and thats why you func **callWasPressed()** didn't called.

You need to set delegate on VC after instantiate your cell.

Like this:

```
AdminPList_TableViewCell.delegate = self
```

I hope it helped you!

Happy coding =D

Comment: OK my friend you are right... I set delegate on VC, but let jump to the  main issue in my question... how to pass ( let selctedProduct) to the other VC... please remember I' new and beginner to Swift so please keep patient with me and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To pass object through other VC you need to follow these 3 steps:

**1st: Create a var on your new VC:**

```
var selectedObject: YourKindObject?
```

**2nd: Pass your object to sender like this:**

```
func cellWasPressed(withData data: productObject) {
// pass productObject as sender
performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditProduct", sender: productObject)}
```

**3rd: On your override method, you should capture your segue ID and passthroug object, like this:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourID(Can be setted on storyboard segue identifier))" {
            var object = sender as! YourKindObject
            let controller = segue.destination as? VC
            controller?. selectedObject = object
    }
}
```

Comment: but here you ignored the let SelectedProduct inside (didSelectItemAt indexPath) of collectioViewCell and it is completely not imported inside the sender in the new VC